# TFS adding new project to the collection issue

Tags: tfs

I am trying to add a new project to the default collection. I am getting the following error message. I renamed the 'DefaultCollection' to 'CollectionNew' last week. I am not sure this is causing the issue. I tried to connect to the Reporting Services using `http://tfs/reports` and received HTTP Status 404 - /Reports error message. Could you please let me know if there are any suggestions? thank you. I am using TFS 2013.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what the answer is but unless you have specific needs you should keep your collection to just one team project.

Comment: I am trying to create a team project for 'development' and another one for 'Release' to organize the permissions for developers. Please suggest.

Comment: Don't do that. It sounds like you want to have multiple teams within an existing team project, not an entire separate team project collection that shares no work item history, build history, etc.

Comment: You aren't managing projects. You are managing a team. One team typically per team project.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will go ahead and create a new collection for the 'Release'(this project contains the production builds) team project. thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

A specific project moves through development -> QA -> Release, the code and the work items MUST be in the same collections as Work items and code are not visible across collections. Collections are more for backup and restore points in very large tfs collections.

Change the name of the collection back to default collection and manage the project process with Workitems and dev,QA and release branches.